# Class property with space in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

Is it possible to do something like the following in Python?

```
class Object:
    
    def `two words`(self):
        return 'Worked!'
```

Depending on the dialect, in SQL you can usually do this with something like `Person.[two words]` or `` Person.`two words` ``, etc. Is it possible to do that in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. The class namespace isn't restricted to only [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), and this is [intentional](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-March/117441.html). However, the usual attribute access syntax `instance.my attr` will not work in this case so you must use [`getattr(instance, "my attr")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) instead.

```
>>> def two_words(self):
...     return 'Worked!'
... 
>>> Object = type("Object", (), {"two words": two_words})
>>> obj = Object()
>>> "two words" in dir(obj)
True
>>> getattr(obj, "two words")
<bound method two_words of <__main__.Object object at 0x10d070ee0>>
>>> getattr(obj, "two words")()
'Worked!'
```

It is also possible to create such an attribute with [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: right, ok I think I'll probably just map a space as you've done or convert it to `_20_` if I need to keep that data (perhaps there are other codepoints not supported by the identifiers). Do you know where in the CPython those identifier restrictions are done?

Comment: I guess that would be here in [`PyUnicode_IsIdentifier`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12367)